FLTK transparent background
As title says I'd like to have a fully transparent main FLTK window/frame background. The below code works just fine:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_PNG_Image.H>
#include <FL/FL_Box.H>

// Global pointers for the GUI objects
Fl_Window* mywindow;
Fl_Box* mypicturebox;
Fl_PNG_Image* img;

//int main() {
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR str, int nWinMode) {

    mywindow = new Fl_Window(295, 290, "Color changer");
    mywindow->color(FL_WHITE);

    // Load some images to use later
    img = new Fl_PNG_Image("D:/Pobrane_2/flower.png");

    // A box for the image
    mypicturebox = new Fl_Box(0, 0, 295, 290);

    // Give it some initial contents
    mypicturebox->image(img);

    mywindow->box(FL_NO_BOX);

    Fl_Button but(50, 80, 100, 20, "Click Me!");
    but.callback([](Fl_Widget* w, void*) {
        Fl_Widget* p = w->parent();
        mywindow->box(FL_FLAT_BOX);
        mywindow->box(FL_NO_BOX);
        mywindow->set_changed();
        mywindow->redraw();
        p->redraw();
        });

    mywindow->show();
    return Fl::run();
}

enter image description here
...UNTIL the app windows is moved:
enter image description here
Then the all effect just gone wrong. As You can see the window appears NOT to be refreshed/updated because in the transparent background we have old/stale content what was relevant ONLY the time when the app window have been created, that is BEFORE the repositioning.
As can bee seen I've added a button whit some refreshing code on it's on-click event but even after executing that forced refresh it's still NOT working as expected!
Any idea how the code can be corrected to have a valid "behind" background content after the window move?

Did you try with enabled double buffering? You can also disable window decoration. I suppose you did not want to do that until you solve this issue...

@DejanLekic Indeed i don't want the window to be decorated, by the way i doubt the decoration/un-dercoation even have helped. Can You hint how to enable the double buffering? Thx!

Fl_Double_Window class has double-buffering enabled.

@DejanLekic Ok. thx. but as far as I do know the double-buffering is rather used for fluid animations...

I don't think that this is really an FLTK question. It's more a general question on how to access the screen background if I understood the question correctly. This is certainly platform dependent, and I'd guess that at least one platform (Wayland) does NOT allow a window to access and display the background, i.e. the contents "behind" the window. As always, for security reasons. My assumption may be wrong, but I don't think that there is a general way to access the desktop - or other window - contents behind a winodw. What do you want to achieve with this kind of transparency?

PS: if you really want useful answers, please post the code you used, not only screenshots. BTW: most such image platforms remove the images after some time which will render this question even less useful after some time.
